# In PHP how to update a document in Apache Solr

Tags: php, solr

I am using [PHP Apache Solr Search Engine Extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) and I am trying to update an existing index in Apache Solr. I know that there is no actual update in Solr, so what I am trying to do is the following (update_by_id):

```
    include "bootstrap.php";
    $options = array
        (
        'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
        'login' => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
        'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        'port' => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
    );

    $client = new SolrClient($options);

    $query = new SolrQuery();

    $query->setQuery('id:1000012');

    $query->setStart(0);

    $query->setRows(1);

//        $query->addField('cat')->addField('features')->addField('id')->addField('timestamp');

    $query_response = $client->query($query);

    $response = $query_response->getResponse();

    if ($response->response->numFound) {
        $second_doc = new SolrInputDocument();
        $second_doc->addField('cat', 'TESTCAT');
        $second_doc->merge($response, true);
        $updateResponse = $client->addDocument($second_doc);
        $client->commit();
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to SolrInputDocument::merge() must be an instance of SolrInputDocument, instance of SolrObject given in /var/www/html/solr-test.dev/update.php on line 44

If this is not the correct way to do it then what is?

Solr Info:

```
Solr Specification Version: 3.6.2.2014.11.01.05.22.12
Solr Implementation Version: 3.6.2 debian - buildd - 2014-11-01 05:22:12
Lucene Specification Version: 3.6.2
Lucene Implementation Version: 3.6.2 debian - buildd - 2014-11-01 05:19:47
```

Comment: What is your Solr version ? There are many differences about latest version

Comment: I've never used the PHP extention, always used GET / POST methods to call Solr... It looks like you can't use the response directly... I'm navigating into the link you mentionned to see a solution, but  it seems complicated... You first have to parse the response, since it may have multiple results... I'll look further

Comment: Maybe found something : `SolrResponse::setParseMode(SolrResponse::PARSE_SOLR_DOC)` says you want a SolrDocument instead of SolrObject. It must affect the type of your `$response`. Then you may use `SolrDocument::getInputDocument` to change it into a `SolrInputDocument`, and can use it as parameter in your `merge`, since it is the expected type... can you give it a try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly got it working after some pointers from @Random. This is how i managed to do it:

```
include "bootstrap.php";
$options = array
(
    'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
    'login' => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
    'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    'port' => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
);
$client = new SolrClient($options);
$query = new SolrQuery();
$query->setQuery('id:1000012');
$query->setStart(0);
$query->setRows(1);
$query_response = $client->query($query);
// I had to set the parsemode to PARSE_SOLR_DOC
$query_response->setParseMode(SolrQueryResponse::PARSE_SOLR_DOC);
$response = $query_response->getResponse();
$doc = new SolrInputDocument();
// used the getInputDocument() to get the old document from the query
$doc = $response->response->docs[0]->getInputDocument();
if ($response->response->numFound) {
    $second_doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    $second_doc->addField('cat', "TESTCAT");
// Notice I removed the second parameter from the merge()
    $second_doc->merge($doc);
    $updateResponse = $client->addDocument($second_doc);
    $client->commit();
}
```

Comment: I am also trying learn to connect to solr.. I am unable to get what is  "bootstrap.php"; and from where we can get it?

Comment: @RakeshKanyal this can help you out http://php.net/manual/ro/solr.examples.php and http://php.net/manual/en/solrclient.construct.php

Comment: Thank you very much.. Now I got it.